# OpenCV: Can't create layer "flatten_1/Shape" of type "Shape"

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I've tried to implement a tensorflow model in opencv dnn. This is the error I've got:

> OpenCV: Can't create layer "flatten_1/Shape" of type "Shape"

I used keras to build my model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (32,32,1), activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())#<== this is the layer that opencv doesnt support

model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
```

I've already tried [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1241):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Reshape

model.add(Reshape((-1,)))
```

But it gave another error

> TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x000001D21EF1A630>

From there I didn't find any solution yet. My question is that is there any replacement for `Flatten()` in keras.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV is used?

Comment: I used OpenCV 3.4.2

Comment: Is it critical to use OpenCV 3.4.2? If not, please try the latest version.

Comment: Actually, it's because I need to use EmguCV which is a wrapper of OpenCV for C#. And the version of OpenCV in EmguCv is just 3.4.2 now.

Comment: Got it. So you can try to use a second argument of `readNetFromTensorflow`: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gad820b280978d06773234ba6841e77e8d . This is a text representation of TensorFlow graph which can be easily modified. Check http://answers.opencv.org/question/183507/opencv-dnn-import-error-for-keras-pretrained-vgg16-model/ or other questions at OpenCV's forum: http://answers.opencv.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:keras/page:1/ .

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev Thank you. I'll dig into those recommendations.

Comment: In case of difficulties you may just add a reference to `.pb` file so I can test it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that OpenCV dnn only allow inference, so the model need to be optimized for inference. I use graph transform tool from tensorflow to do that.

```
from tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms import TransformGraph

graph = TransformGraph(graph,
            ["input_1"], # inputs nodes
            ["dense_2/Softmax"], # outputs nodes
            ['fold_constants()',
            'strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="None,32,32,1")',
            'remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)',
            'fold_batch_norms',
            'fold_old_batch_norms'
            ])
```

Comment: in TensorFlow tools has no attribute "graph_transforms" at version 1.14.0

Answer (score 3):

Try to change Flatten to below:

```
#model.add(Flatten())
a, b, c, d = model.output_shape
a = b * c * d
model.add(Permute([1, 2, 3]))  # Indicate NHWC data layout
model.add(Reshape((a,)))
```

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10135

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.